# Running sql script on MYSQL database each day

Tags: mysql, webserver

I have two scripts, worker.sql and updater.sql I need to run on my website daily. Rather than having to log into the console etc I would rather be able to run the scripts daily, say at 00:05 and 00:10 respectively automatically.

I would also like to be able to invoke these scripts from the admin console of my website, but that can come later.

I have a full website hosting package and have cron job availability but I am not sure how to go about it, also my issue is these sql files will be updated regularly and will be quite large.

here is an example of one of the two files:

```
/* Title        : Database ORGANIZATION Script
/* Author       : David Cummings
/* Date         : 10th October 2017
/* Description  : This script runs through the database and adjusts
/*              : input to the correct formats. This will make the 
/*              : data all uniform in apparence.
/*              : V1.2

/* Remove Rogue spots
DELETE FROM spotting WHERE location IS NULL;
DELETE FROM spotting WHERE uname IS NULL;
DELETE FROM spotting WHERE type IS NULL;

/* Edit Operaters
SET operater = replace(operater, 'SAS', 'Scandinavian Airlines System');
SET operater = replace(operater, 'Easyjet', 'easyJet');

/* Update the Make
UPDATE spotting 
SET make = replace(make, 'airbus', 'Airbus');
SET make = replace(make, 'beoing', 'Boeing');
SET make = replace(make, 'boeing', 'Boeing');
SET make = replace(make, 'ATR', 'Aerospatiale');
SET make = replace(make, 'de', 'Bombardier');

/* Update the Model
UPDATE spotting
SET model = replace(model, 'ERJ170-200STD', 'ERJ-175STD (170-200)');
SET model = replace(model, '737-%', 'B737-%');

/* Misc Types
SET model = replace(model, '%/F', 'F');

/* Boeing Range types
SET model = replace(model, '%(ER)', '%ER');
SET model = replace(model, '%(LR)', '%LR');
SET model = replace(model, '%(QC)', '%QC');
SET model = replace(model, '%(BCF)', '%BCF');
SET model = replace(model, '%/W/W', '%/W');

/* Airbus Winglet Types
SET model = replace(model, '%/SL' '%/W');
SET model = replace(model, '%/S' '%/W');

/* Aerospatiale Types
```

---

Comment: Use events? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html and store script in a procedure.  then you can call procedure from admin pages later if desired, and/or run according to event schedule.

Comment: I'd still go with cron. What is exactly your problem in solving this via cron?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do it. Would Cron be able to run a full SQL script or would it be line by line